# Is there any way i can somehow have two sounds play at once in c# console app?

Tags: c#, audio, console-application, soundplayer

Im working on a text game in c#. But i wanted to have multiple sounds at once. So i tried to use SoundPlayer. But whenever i loaded up another sound, it just cut off the other one. If that makes sense. Im new to programming, so please try to explain like im 5!

Comment: @RyanWilson And how would you make a new soundplayer? I dont get it.

Comment: You can prototype with Beep and see if you can play them together. You can consider extending to others

Comment: can you add some clear examples of what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you have say 2 different sounds that you want to play together.

Below example is for Console.Beep, which can be extended to other sounds

You can replace Console.Beep() with other sounds that you want to play

---

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Add above 2 to your Namespace

```
//First sound you want to play

var first = await Task.Run(() => Console.Beep());

//Optional Delay
await Task.Delay(500); //Does not halt the current thread

//Second sound you want to play
var second = await Task.Run(() => Console.Beep(500,1000));
```

Comment: sorry, i know i have to sound like a complete idiot here but i honestly dont know. Why am i getting an error for the whole thing?

Comment: sure. uhh it says "cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable"

Comment: your code works, however it still stops the music before :/

Comment: sorry couldn't test, I edited the code. It was synchronous before.

Answer (score 0):

I had been struggling with the same issue.....

The short answer is you can't. The system will only permit one channel to the sound interface within any given process. As such, when you start a new sound, the previous one terminates.